# Python Beautiful Soup: How to extract text next to a tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have following HTML

```
<p>
<b>Father:</b> Michael Haughton
<br>
<b>Mother:</b> Diane
<br><b>Brother:</b> 
Rashad Haughton<br>
<b>Husband:</b> <a href="/people/540/000024468/">R. Kelly</a> (m. 1994, annulled that same year)
<br><b>Boyfriend:</b> <a href="/people/420/000109093/">Damon Dash</a> (Roc-a-Fella co-CEO)<br></p>
```

I have to separate heading and text, for instance, *Mother*: **Diane**..

So in the end I would have a list of dictionaries as:

```
[{"label":"Mother","value":"Diane"}]
```

I was trying the below but not working:

```
def parse(u):
    u = u.rstrip('\n')
    r = requests.get(u, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        html = r.text.strip()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        headings = soup.select('table p')
        for h in headings:
            b = h.find('b')
            if b is not None:
                print(b.text)
                print(h.text + '\n')
                print('=================================')


url = 'http://www.nndb.com/people/742/000024670/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

#html = '''<p>
#<b>Father:</b> Michael Haughton
#<br>
#<b>Mother:</b> Diane
#<br><b>Brother:</b> 
#Rashad Haughton<br>
#<b>Husband:</b> <a href="/people/540/000024468/">R. Kelly</a> (m. 1994, annulled that same year)
#<br><b>Boyfriend:</b> <a href="/people/420/000109093/">Damon Dash</a> (Roc-a-Fella co-CEO)<br></p>'''

page = urlopen('http://www.nndb.com/people/742/000024670/')
source = page.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

needed_p = soup.find_all('p')[8]

bs = needed_p.find_all('b')

res = {}

for b in bs:
    if b.find_next('a').text:
        res[b.text] = b.find_next('a').text.strip().strip('\n')
    if b.next_sibling != ' ':
        res[b.text] = b.next_sibling.strip().strip('\n')

res
```

output:

```
{'Brother:': 'Rashad Haughton',
 'Mother:': 'Diane',
 'Husband:': 'R. Kelly',
 'Father:': 'Michael Haughton',
 'Boyfriend:': 'Damon Dash'}
```

**EDIT**:
For additional info on top of the page:

```
... (code above) ...
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

needed_p = soup.find_all('p')[1:4] + [soup.find_all('p')[8]] # here explicitly selecting needed p-tags for further parsing

res = {}

for p in needed_p:
    bs = p.find_all('b')
    for b in bs:
        if b.find_next('a').text:
            res[b.text] = b.find_next('a').text.strip().strip('\n')
        if b.next_sibling != ' ':
            res[b.text] = b.next_sibling.strip().strip('\n')

res
```

output:

```
{'Race or Ethnicity:': 'Black',
 'Husband:': 'R. Kelly',
 'Died:': '25-Aug',
 'Nationality:': 'United States',
 'Executive summary:': 'R&B singer, died in plane crash',
 'Mother:': 'Diane',
 'Birthplace:': 'Brooklyn, NY',
 'Born:': '16-Jan',
 'Boyfriend:': 'Damon Dash',
 'Sexual orientation:': 'Straight',
 'Occupation:': 'Singer',
 'Cause of death:': 'Accident - Airplane',
 'Brother:': 'Rashad Haughton',
 'Remains:': 'Interred,',
 'Gender:': 'Female',
 'Father:': 'Michael Haughton',
 'Location of death:': 'Marsh Harbour, Abaco Island, Bahamas'}
```

For *precisely this* page you also can scrape High school, for example, this way:

```
res['High School'] = soup.find_all('p')[9].text.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Comment: @Rightleg, what precisely you don't understand?

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy When running against the URL `url = 'http://www.nndb.com/people/742/000024670/'` it gives error:

`res[b.text] = b.next_sibling.strip().strip('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: I understand everything. I just think that a piece of code without explanation is not really useful for people trying to understand the problem - regardless of the quality of the code.

Comment: @Volatil3, I updated my solution to work when processing url, please check if it suits you

Comment: @Volatil3, most probably the error happened because you passed all `p` tags in processing, and not all of them contained expected elements, that's why `NoneType` error occured on `b.next_sibling.strip().strip('\n')`

Comment: It worked but did not fetch all values and I guess it is because of `needed_p = soup.find_all('p')[8]`

Comment: Oh well.. I see what I posted above.. you are not wrong. Sorry

Comment: Initially you requested only current `res` values as an output, no criminal here=)

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy Yes :-) - In case I need to fetch from `Born:` till end, guess I need to iterate all `P`s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151476/discussion-between-dmitriy-fialkovskiy-and-volatil3).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) tag attribute.
This gives you either the next `NavigableString` or the next `Tag`, depending on what it finds first.

Here is how you can use it:

```
html = """..."""            
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

bTags = soup.find_all('b')
for it_tag in bTags:
    print(it_tag.string)
    print(it_tag.next_sibling)
```

Output:

```
Father:
 Michael Haughton

Mother:
 Diane

Brother:

Rashad Haughton
Husband:

Boyfriend:
```

This seems a bit off.
It's partly because of the line breaks and the blanks, which you can get rid of easily with the `str.strip` method.

Still, the `Boyfriend` and `Husband` entries are lacking a value.
It's because `next_sibling` is either a `NavigableString` (ie a `str`) or a `Tag`.
The blank between the `<b>` tag and the `<a>` tag here is interpreted as a non-empty text:

```
<b>Boyfriend:</b> <a href="/people/420/000109093/">Damon Dash</a>
                 ^
```

If it were absent, `<b>Boyfriend:</b>`'s next sibling would be the `<a>` tag.
Since it's present, you have to check:

- Whether the next sibling is a string or a tag;
- If it is a string, whether it contains only whitespace.

If the next sibling is a whitespace-only string, then the information you're looking for is that `NavigableString`'s next sibling, which will be a `<a>` tag.

Edited code:

```
bTags = soup.find_all('b')

for it_tag in bTags:
    print(it_tag.string)

    nextSibling = it_tag.next_sibling
    if nextSibling is not None:
        if isinstance(nextSibling, str):
            if nextSibling.isspace():
                print(it_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.string.strip())
            else:
                print(nextSibling.strip())

        elif isinstance(it_tag.next_sibling, bs4.Tag):
            print(it_tag.next_sibling.string)
```

Output:

```
Father:
Michael Haughton
Mother:
Diane
Brother:
Rashad Haughton
Husband:
R. Kelly
Boyfriend:
Damon Dash
```

Now you can easily build your dictionary:

```
entries = {}
bTags = soup.find_all('b')

for it_tag in bTags:
    key = it_tag.string.replace(':', '')
    value = None

    nextSibling = it_tag.next_sibling
    if nextSibling is not None:
        if isinstance(nextSibling, str):
            if nextSibling.isspace():
                value = it_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling.string.strip()
            else:
                value = nextSibling.strip()

        elif isinstance(it_tag.next_sibling, bs4.Tag):
            value = it_tag.next_sibling.string

    entries[key] = value
```

Output dictionary:

```
{'Father': 'Michael Haughton',
 'Mother': 'Diane',
 'Brother': 'Rashad Haughton',
 'Husband': 'R. Kelly',
 'Boyfriend': 'Damon Dash'}
```

Comment: I am getting error ` line 27, in parse
    if it_tag.next_sibling.isspace():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isspace'`

Comment: @Volatil3 I edited my code. Please check if it works for you. I added a `None` check, and I condensed the tests.

Comment: `key = it_tag.string.replace(':', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`